# How do I display <Object> tag in webpage to input data other than Windows Explorer

Tags: html, object, xhtml, datasource

I have recently learnt how to input data to my webpage from a txt file using  tag and DATASRC. However when using the following code, it only works in Internet Explorer.

```
<OBJECT ID="league"
     CLASSID="clsid:333C7BC4-460F-11D0-BC04-0080C7055A83"
     BORDER="0"
     WIDTH="0"
     HEIGHT="0">
 <PARAM NAME="DataURL" VALUE="div1.txt" />
 <PARAM NAME="UseHeader" VALUE="false" />
</OBJECT>
  <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <!--DWLayoutTable-->
    <tr> 
      <td><b>Team</b></td>
      <td width="30"><b>P</b></td>
      <td width="30"><b>W</b></td>
      <td width="30"><b>L</b></td>
      <td width="30"><b>F</b></td>
      <td width="30"><b>A</b></td>
      <td width="30"><b>Pts</b></td>
    </tr></table>

    <TABLE WIDTH="100%" DATASRC="#league" datapagesize="10" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

 <TR>  
    <TD><SPAN DATAFLD="column1"></SPAN></TD>
    <TD width="30"><SPAN DATAFLD="column2"></SPAN></TD>      
    <TD width="30"><SPAN DATAFLD="column3"></SPAN></TD>
    <TD width="30"><SPAN DATAFLD="column4"></SPAN></TD>
    <TD width="30"><SPAN DATAFLD="column5"></SPAN></TD>
    <TD width="30"><SPAN DATAFLD="column6"></SPAN></TD>
    <TD width="30"><SPAN DATAFLD="column7"></SPAN></TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Is there any way I can get Firefox, Chrome, and the iphone/ipad to see the data that is imported?

I have very basic html and css skills but learning all the time. I was going to use PHP but the server doesn't support it.

Any suggestions would be helpful otherwise I will have to continue importing tabular data in dreamweaver.

cheers
Richard

Comment: According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531356(v=vs.85).aspx) the object is an ActiveX control and will work only in Internet Explorers.

Comment: sounds like an answer to me

Comment: I feared this was the case, I'm doing an online course so why on earth teach me something that most of the planet won't see!!

Comment: @RichardSmith - HTML these days is a pretty fast moving target. It can be hard, and expensive, to keep course materials up to date. But it rather sounds like your online course suppliers aren't even trying. Care to name and shame them?

Comment: @home please make this an answer